# MDX Query with NON EMPTY not filtering NULLs

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx

I am currently looking into a piece of `MDX` Code where `NON EMPTY` is not able to filter NULL values.This actually lists the DEMO_KPI for all the accounts for yesterday. Since not all accounts are active on that day the resultset should be very small one. The `MDX` uses predefined sets for finding yesterday. I think the complexity for finding yesterday is by design from the past. I am a novice MDX dev trying to find out why this query is returning NULLs and it still is  a mystery.

```
    SELECT 
       NON EMPTY { [yesterday_1] } ON COLUMNS,
       NON EMPTY { [Account].[Account ID].[All].CHILDREN } ON ROWS
    FROM [DEMO]
    WHERE ( [DIM_1].[Hierarchy_1].&[xyz], [Dim_2].[Hierarchy_2].&[abc], [Measures].[Demo KPI] )
```

The `MDX` uses Calculated Measures which I have represented here as a single set of code..

```
    WITH 
      SET [base_yesterday_1] AS
        FILTER(
         [Date].[Date].[Date].MEMBERS,
         [Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER.NEXTMEMBER.PROPERTIES("CALENDAR DATE NO PADDING")=format(NOW(), 'M/d/yyyy')
         )
      SET [cyesterday_1] AS
       EXISTS(
         [Date].[Calendar].[Date].MEMBERS, 
         [base_yesterday_1]
         ).ITEM(0).ITEM(0)
      SET [yesterday_1] AS 
        {cyesterday_1.ITEM(0).ITEM(0)}
    SELECT 
      NON EMPTY { [yesterday_1] } ON COLUMNS,
      NON EMPTY { [Account].[Account ID].[All].CHILDREN } ON ROWS
    FROM [DEMO]
    WHERE ([DIM_1].[Hierarchy_1].&[xyz], [Dim_2].[Hierarchy_2].&[abc], [Measures].[Demo KPI])
```

The resultset would be sparse because of all the nulls returns and is affecting client performance.

Have tried replacing `EXISTS` with `NONEMPTY` which doesn't help in filtering the NULLS either.Is there a way to solve this issue or rewrite the `MDX` statements so the result doesn't contain NULLS?

Answer (score 0):

`NON EMPTY` for the rows excludes rows from display that would have `NULL` in **all** columns, and `NON EMPTY` for the columns excludes columns from the display that would show `NULL` in **all** rows.

I am not sure about your data contents. But maybe it helps to add in quotes the name of the measure group containing the `[Measures].[Demo KPI]` measure as third argument to the `EXISTS`. And maybe it helps to add a `HAVING` clause directly before the `ON ROWS` which could use any condition that can be evaluated for each row to restrict the rows to display.

Comment: Hi Frank - because custom sets are not context aware (apart from the WHERE clause) does this have an impact on the user putting `currentmember` in the set `[base_yesterday_1]` ?

Comment: @whytheq Good point! It could be that `[base_yesterday_1]` is always the empty set, as the `[Date].[Date].CURRENTMEMBER` is the default member of the date hierarchy, which presumably is the `All` member which does not have a `NEXTMEMBER`.